# Curl post request without returning data

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Hello i'm using a curl post and i dont know why i still get returned data if i set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to 0 or false.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://twingoo.ro/profil.php?user='.$user.'&scrape=true';

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); 




$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

return result:

```
  {"url":"http:\/\/twingoo.ro\/profil.php?user=53","type":"website","title":"Stan Elena","image":[{"url":"http:\/\/twingoo.ro\/images\/users\/53\/Hydrangeas.jpg"}],"description":"Acesta este profilul meu pe twingoo.ro, intra si voteaza-ma pentru a putea castiga un super premiu!\nTe poti inscrie si tu gratuit pe twingoo.ro alaturi de mine.\nTwingoo Social Group powered by Websoftit.ro","site_name":"Twingoo","see_also":["http:\/\/www.twingoo.ro\/"],"updated_time":"2014-03-25T10:10:14+0000","admins":[{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","name":"Sima Cristian Alexandru","url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/sima.cristianalexandru"}],"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Comment: There is an error in your script; 'curl_setopt($curl,' should be 'curl_setopt($ch,'

Comment: true, i changed it to sh but still it returns me the result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), when `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is set to TRUE, the result will be returned when calling `curl_exec()`. If it is FALSE, then it will be simply output without `curl_exec()` returning the result.

However, if you have set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to FALSE and `curl_exec()` still returns a string instead of a boolean, that's another story (shouldn't be happening though).

Comment: yep, it's set to false but still returnin a result :(

Comment: OK, let's clarify - by "return result", you mean you get the result as a string and it is actually stored in the `$response` variable, right?

Comment: yep, i edited my 1st post you can see what it returns to me. I just want to execute the request but i dont want to return nothing because i have the code on my header to refresh facebook cache and it'll look as crap

Comment: You cannot have it both ways. If the option is 0, the result will be output (i.e. displayed on the page), and `$response` will be wither TRUE or FALSE, which I suppose is what you don't want. If the option is 1, nothing will be displayed, only the result of the request will be stored in the `$response` (the string you get, or FALSE if it fails). You don't have to do anything with `$response` - if you leave it, nothing will be displayed. I really cannot think of a scenario where you want _absolutely nothing_ returned from the request. At the very least, you should know if it succeeded or not.